# Required fieldset html [Angular]

Tags: angularjs, html, forms

There is a way to required form fieldset and don't every input?

**My point:** the user can choose what to fill but will not have to fill all of the fieldset inputs

I have this two:

**1:**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> legend </legend>
  <label for="id"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="name">
  <label for="id2"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2">
</fieldset>
```

**2:**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> legend </legend>
  <label for="id"> label </label>
  <input type="radio" id="id" name="name">
  <label for="id2"> label </label>
  <input type="radio" id="id2" name="name">
</fieldset>
```

I use **Angular** if it can be simplest.

Comment: So let me just get this right. The user has to fill out the form but can leave some of it empty?

Comment: The user must to fill something in the fieldset but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 2 options, the easiest thing to do would be:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> legend </legend>
  <label for="id"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="name" ng-required="!name2">
  <label for="id2"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" ng-required="!name">
</fieldset>
```

Edit: Since they are dynamic, you would probably need a model to help you out on each fieldset.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> legend </legend>
  <label for="id"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="name" ng-model="fieldSetHasValue" ng-change="fieldSetHasValue = true">
  <label for="id2"> label </label>
  <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" ng-model="fieldSetHasValue" ng-change="fieldSetHasValue = true">
</fieldset>
```

And then before you submit, check if fieldSetHasValue is true. This is just one of many ways to accomplish this and there will no doubt be some kinks to work through if you implement this. This is just a quick off the top of my head solution without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Its dynamic. Users can add more inputs with different types to the fieldset.

Comment: You have another solution?